# Deleting empty worksheets

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write a code to delete empty worksheets in a workbook. So far I have been able to delete worksheets starting at the highest to the lowest  using the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim objExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)
i = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


    Do Until i = 2
        objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Delete()
        i = i - 1
    Loop
```

I had a look on the internet, but didn't find something that can be useful. Can anyone help me by guiding me to the right direction where I can obtain information on how to detect for empty worksheets in a single workbook using VB.net only.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick in vb.net

```
Private Sub DeleteBlankWorksheets(xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook)
    For i As Integer = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i), Excel.Worksheet)
        If Convert.ToInt64(ws.UsedRange.CountLarge) <= 1 Then
            ws.Delete()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Replace your entire loop with a call to this function, passing your `objWorkBook` object as the parameter.

```
Dim objExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)

DeleteBlankWorksheets(objWorkbook)
```

'Add this to save the file

```
objWorkbook.Save()
objWorkbook.Close()  'closes the files
```

'If you have trouble with the file object being still opened, meaning you   can see the EXCEL.exe in the task manager then add the following code

```
 For Each instance As Process In Process.GetProcesses
     If InStr(instance.MainWindowTitle, Textbox1.Text) <> 0 Then p.Kill()
 Next
```

NOTE: It is better to make sure to dispose of all of your excel objects (applications, workbooks, worksheets, etc) than to kill processes. This will ensure all data is preserved as intended without side effects. If you find you have extra excel.exe instances running, make sure to double check everything is disposed and released properly.

Comment: Thank you for the code I tried it out and it seems to work for only one empty sheet and when that is deleted that remaining sheet stays there and an error appears. I would show the image but low reputation so cannot. I will explain though.  In the subroutine  DeleteBlankWorksheets the line  that starts with -  Dim ws As  -  has the following error. COM expection was unhandled.  When the program has deleted one of theworksheet, the file is opened and I think due to this the error occurs. Is this correct? This is only a though

Comment: @ArranRai Whoops!. I updated the for loop, my mistake! Should work a lot better now. I reversed the order in which it looks at the worksheets (so it starts from the last one and works backwards).

Comment: @ArranRai to answer your question, it was erroring because the loop counter was greater than the count of worksheets after deleting one. Example, total count of worksheets is 4, and worksheets 3 and 4 are blank. `i = 3` and worksheet 3 gets deleted, now worksheet 4 is worksheet 3 and now `i = 4` (which now doesn't exist). The COM exception is thrown because it would be accessing worksheet 4, but there are now only 3 worksheets so number 4 doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly. The program doesn't save the workbook, so if anyone else wants to save the file.  I will edit the code above written a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
Sub DeleteBlankWs() 

    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    For Each ws In Worksheets 
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) = 0 Then 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
            ws.Delete 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
        End If 
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

**I created an excel with 5 sheets, sheet 2 and 4 are empty, then I edited a micro and run it (F5 key or the green play icon)...**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. I put your subroutine to be called instead of this line objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Delete().  An error appeared stating that worksheets are not declared. I'm thinking that they needs to be parameters passed to the subroutine so that the function understands the file that I'm trying to check. Is this correct?

Comment: see my update, with best mspaint quality ;) ... you apply the code for the file you work with.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation but as I mentioned in my question statement I'm only looking to do this by vb.net only and not any other way, not even macros.. But thank you again